# Error using "Theme.AppCompat" with Android Studio 2.1.0

Tags: android

In my android project, I am getting the error "Cannot find symbol for Theme.AppCompat" while using it in styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I have included the app compat dependency in my gradle file:

'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

I tried finding the solution all over internet but nothing helps. Can someone help me with this..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, it would be the Java or XML where you are trying to reference `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: @CommonsWare .. Thanks for pointing it out. I am using it in styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let you know that you're not alone.  Everything was working fine in the app I was developing, testing heavily on a marshmallow nexus 5 and a lollipop samsung tablet.  I must have let something automatically update, because now I'm having problems with appcompat.

Here's an example of what's going wrong:

in a layout XML I have an edit text with style specified:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
```

This will cause 'Error inflating class EditText'

if I create a style for the edit text in v21 styles with a parent of 'Widget.AppCompat.EditText' and specify the background (my color, or drawable, or ?android:attr/editTextStyle) it will work - though all of these options lose the edittext underline style.

If I specify background of ?attr/editTextStyle it will fail to inflate, which I assume is the default, it will fail to inflate.  Likewise, if I leave any style tag off of the edit text, it will also fail to inflate.

Glad I'm not alone, but I wish this wasn't a thing...